Connecting Clerk SVIX Webhooks to Firebase HTTPS Cloud functions
Scenario: You have a NExtJS project using clerk for authentication. You want to hook it up to Firebase via google cloud functions and Clerk Webhooks for proper user management. How do you do it.
SVIX does an excellent job at documenting their API, but for some reason, it doesn't log the errors of why it has failed. So as a dev, you're left to do a lot of trial and error until somehow, you make it work.
After a lot of trial and error, I have finally managed to get SVIX Webhooks working in NodeJS Typescript Firebase Cloud functions.
I do not ever want anyone to go through this.


Here's the code. I'm assuming you already have the webhook setup in Clerk Dashboard
export const yourWebhookName = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

const wh = new Webhook(clerkSigningSecret);

var msg;

var payload = JSON.stringify(req.body);

var moddedHeaders = req.headers as WebhookRequiredHeaders | WebhookUnbrandedRequiredHeaders | Record<string, string>

console.log(`Here is svix id: ${svixID} and here is timestamp: ${svixTimestamp} and here is signature: ${svixSignature} and here is payload: ${payload}`);

try {
    msg = wh.verify(payload, moddedHeaders);
} catch (err) {
    console.log("It seems MSG is baaddd. Here's the error", JSON.stringify(err));
    res.status(400).json({});

    return;
}

console.log("It seems MSG is good and this is msg", JSON.stringify(msg));

var event = req.body.type;

if (event == "user.created") {
    console.log("New user");

    res.status(200).json({});
    return;
} else {
    if (event == "user.updated") {
        console.log("Updated user");

        res.status(200).json({});
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("Deleted user");

        res.status(200).json({});
        return;
    }
}
});

Happy coding.
